# Nonlinear ODE, closed form solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does the following ODE have a closed form solution?
$$y'+\frac{1}{y}=-\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Maple and Wolfram alpha give no result. Seems like there is no obvious solution. Also note that $y'=-1/y-1/x$ is sigular for $y=0$ and $x=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y'+\dfrac{1}{y}=-\dfrac{1}{x}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\dfrac{1}{x}=-\dfrac{1}{y}$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\dfrac{y}{x}=-1$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $x=e^{-t}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{-e^{-t}}=-e^t\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

$\therefore-e^ty\dfrac{dy}{dt}+e^ty=-1$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dt}-y=e^{-t}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf or in http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v43/issue_3/IJAM_43_3_01.pdf